# JSF 2.x: When a tag is included several times in the page, how to use another backing bean for each inclusion?

Tags: jsf-2.2

In JSF 2.2 (incl. CDI beans) I want to view elements of a list.
There is already a file to show a single element, let's say either a tag file or a fragment that can be included via `<ui:include>`.
Each element view shall use its own "backing bean". How do I implement this?

My starting point:

main.xhtml:

```
<t:dataList value="#{bean.elements}"  var="myElement">
    <ui:include src="element.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="elementId" value="#{myElement.id}" />
        <ui:param name="context" value="#{otherBean.context}" />
        <ui:param name="callerClientId"
                  value="#{ ... something like "this.clientId" .. }" />
    </ui:include>
</t:dataList>
```

element.xhtml:

```
<ui:fragment>
 <!--- 
  each included element.xhtml should get its own elementBean, 
  something like the following must happen:
  "elementBean = elementBeanFactory.getOrCreate(elementId, context, callerClientId)"
 --->
    <h:inputText value="#{elementBean.value}"> ... 
</ui:fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

1. Encapsulate your code as a [composite component](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/)
2. Create the "beans" that you wish to use & put them in a List
3. Iterate over the list and render the custom component - passing in an instance of the bean

Wouldn't this solve the problem at hand?

Comment: You are right, this is the way I solved this kind of problem with JSF 1.x (using `<ui.include>` instead of composite components, of course). I just thought the combination of JSFs new scopes and the EL 2.2 would allow me to "decouple" the classes a bit. I always thought the parent `bean` should not know about the 'beans' that are used by the elements - similiar to the standard JSF components which I can use without referring to them.